# Mobile Safari and ArcGIS JavaScript API Errors

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, osx, safari

So in creating an application that uses the [LaywerSwipe widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_swipe.html) the application displays fine on iOS but I am unable to move the scope or slider. I get the following errors from init.js :

[image]

It keeps spitting out these errors for a bit and I can't understand why.